# Thread safe file access in web project?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching

I need a local File Cache in a web project. I am testing 
[fc.codeplex.com](http://fc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/FileCache/FileCache.cs)
which "is a concrete implementation of the .Net Framework 4's System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache that uses the local filesystem as the target location". In our tests it's been working without a problem. My question is if you think the try-catch code in GetStream is thread safe:

```
///AccessTimeout is a TimeSpan to optionally specify a timeout.

/// <summary>
/// This function servies to centralize file stream access within this class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <param name="mode"></param>
/// <param name="access"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private FileStream GetStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
{
    FileStream stream = null;
    TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
    TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();
    while (stream == null)
    {
        try
        {
            stream = File.Open(path, mode, access);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
            totalTime += interval;

            //if we've waited too long, throw the original exception.
            if (AccessTimeout.Ticks != 0)
            {
                if (totalTime > AccessTimeout)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return stream;
}
```